# How to change GNOME top panel colour and transparency levels?

Tags: gnome, 15.10, customization, panel

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I want to know if I can change the top panel's colour and transparency levels?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To do this you will need to install the GNOME Shell extension [**Activities Configurator**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/). For installation instructions and for instructions on how to get into the settings panel for any extension which has one go [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/757326/364819).

And then as well as many other things you will be able to change the top panel colour and its level of transparency:

[image]

Comment: It changes the ison without any option to disable the feature. Not good extension. But also does not work for me. Still top panel is gray

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a theme, it probably comes with a top bar color. I had to follow the steps here [Why is Shell theme disabled in Gnome Tweak Tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545741/why-is-shell-theme-disabled-in-gnome-tweak-tool) to enable my theme's default top bar color (which works much nicer as a theme).