# The style of menubar and right-click context menu is gone for all gnome apps

Tags: 16.04, gnome, themes, menu-bar

The style of menubar and right-click context menu is gone for all gnome apps. For example gnome-calculator, eog were broken, but gitk is good. Here's the screenshot.

[image]

I've tried to re-install gnome-terminal, gnome-common, gnome-tweak-tool, but can't find a way to restore it.

My env:

```
Awesome wm + gnome-terminal mostly,
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux,
```

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading to 17.10 from 16.04. My upgrade was funky and unintended as I copied a file into /etc/apt (thinking two boxes were running the same version).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on in artful which uses gnome, and here is how I fixed it or at least worked around it.

The first thing you might check to see is if this is a problem with a particular login or a global problem. If you have another account switch to that to see if there is a problem with that account. Alternatively, one can create a new account and login to that

In my case, yes, there was something configuration in my home directory.

What I did then is change the desktop settings to something different. For this I used gnome-tweak-tool and under Appearance and Themes I selected another theme. (I had installed gnome-themes-ubuntu first).

This is also spelled out in https://askubuntu.com/a/546492/415568

The only tricky part was that since my styling was messed up it was hard to see whether the on/off boxes were selected.