# Warning symbol on the Shell line in Tweaks

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-tweaks

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Gnome 3.36.8 as shown in **About** in the **Settings program**. But **Appearance** in the **Tweaks program**, the *Shell line* shows a warning symbol (⚠) and the shell information is missing.
[image: Settings hard copy extract]
[image: Tweaks Appearance window]
Everything seems to work correctly, but I would like to know why this **⚠**!

How can I investigate?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Shell theme disabled in Gnome Tweak Tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545741/why-is-shell-theme-disabled-in-gnome-tweak-tool)

Comment: Thank you Terrance. I re-install user themes, restart gnome shell... the slide **User themes** is disabled each time I restart Tweaks... time waste But the topic 545741 is clear : this line is about **theme** of the shell. So I have the default theme. The warning should not appear. All is OK.

Answer (score 0):

[Why is Shell theme disabled in Gnome Tweak Tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545741/why-is-shell-theme-disabled-in-gnome-tweak-tool) (see below) give me the answer. This line is about shell theme (the title of the section). I think the warning symbol should not appear (in my opinion).