# X2Go no longer works in 22.04, black screen, then closes

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, mate, x2go, nomachine

X2Go with MATE desktop used to work fine, but after upgrading to 22.04 it has broken, and I haven't been able to fix it for months.  If I try to connect with MATE (from Windows X2Go client), it shows a "New session started" popup and then shows a blank window briefly, and finally closes.  On the server, running `dmesg --follow` at the same time, I see:

```
[14238.559864] show_signal_msg: 3 callbacks suppressed
[14238.559867] mate-session[129320]: segfault at 7f3200000060 ip 00007f325d65f52f sp 00007fff9ee3b250 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2404.29[7f325d623000+83000]
[14238.559876] Code: 57 82 fc ff 49 8b 9c 24 70 01 00 00 48 85 db 74 4e 49 89 c5 eb 0a 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 85 db 74 3f 48 8b 2b 48 89 de 48 8b 5b 08 <48> 8b 45 08 48 85 c0 74 e8 4c 39 e8 7f e3 49 8b bc 24 70 01 00 00
```

If I try to use something other than MATE, like "Connection to local desktop" (which also used to work), it shows "Select desktop" with `:0` and `:1` as options.  If I select either, and hit "View Only" or "Full Access", I just get a black window and nothing in `dmesg` (and nothing in `dmesg` if I try the "Terminal" session type).

Same results from another Windows computer that used to work, so it's a server issue, not a client issue.

If I try to connect to "Terminal", on the client, in the folder `C:\Users\[Client username]\.x2go\S-[Server username]-50-1672416167_stRTERMINAL_dp32` there is a file named `sessions` that contains:

```
Loop: WARNING! Unrecognized session type 'unix-kde-depth_32'. Assuming agent session.
Auth: WARNING! Failed to read data from the X auth command.
Auth: WARNING! Generating a fake cookie for X authentication.
Loop: WARNING! Could not retrieve the X server authentication cookie.
```

and a file called `session.log` that contains:

```
NXPROXY - Version 3.5.0

Copyright (C) 2001, 2010 NoMachine.
See http://www.nomachine.com/ for more information.

Info: Proxy running in client mode with pid '33776'.
Session: Starting session at 'Fri Dec 30 11:02:50 2022'.
Info: Connecting to remote host 'localhost:50767'.
Info: Connection to remote proxy 'localhost:50767' established.
Info: Connection with remote proxy completed.
Warning: Unrecognized session type 'unix-kde-depth_32'. Assuming agent session.
Warning: Failed to read data from the X auth command.
Warning: Generated a fake cookie for X authentication.
Info: Using ADSL link parameters 512/24/1/0.
Info: Using cache parameters 4/4096KB/8192KB/8192KB.
Info: Using pack method '16m-jpeg-9' with session 'unix-kde-depth_32'.
Info: Using ZLIB data compression 1/1/32.
Info: Using ZLIB stream compression 4/4.
Info: No suitable cache file found.
Info: Forwarding X11 connections to display 'localhost:0'.
Session: Session started at 'Fri Dec 30 11:02:50 2022'.
Info: Established X server connection.
Info: Using shared memory parameters 0/0K.
Session: Terminating session at 'Fri Dec 30 11:02:53 2022'.
Session: Session terminated at 'Fri Dec 30 11:02:53 2022'.
```

and a file called `options` that contains:

```
nx/nx,root=/cygdrive/C/Users/[Client username]/X2GO~1,connect=localhost,cookie=ecfd5c17918a53bcfa5a66a50eba7712,port=50767,errors=/cygdrive/C/Users/[Client username]/X2GO~1/S-C536~1/sessions:50
```

On the server, I get nothing in `~> tail -f $HOME/.xsession-x2go-errors`, nothing new appears in `~/.x2go`, and `~> tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep x2go` says:

```
Dec 30 11:02:49 shuttle /usr/bin/x2gostartagent: successfully started X2Go Agent session with ID [Server username]-50-1672416167_stRTERMINAL_dp32
Dec 30 11:03:23 shuttle /usr/bin/x2gosetkeyboard: /home/[Server username]/.x2go/C-[Server username]-50-1672416167_stRTERMINAL_dp32/keyboard did not appear within 30s after agent startup
```

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling every x2go package on the server, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`? I don't use x2go but I do know that other tools like x2x and barrier don't work with Wayland and I had to manually switch back to x11 after an Ubuntu upgrade (but I forget which version made Wayland the default). Just a thought.

Comment: @codlord  `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` → `tty`

Comment: I was never able to get this to work.  Completely uninstalling and deleting all configuration files and reinstalling didn't fix anything.  Asking on the mailing list got no response.  Finally I've discovered `xrdp` which works (over SSH,etc), and works better (remote is same desktop as local), so I will use that from now on: https://askubuntu.com/a/1409120/5032 https://askubuntu.com/questions/545741/why-is-shell-theme-disabled-in-gnome-tweak-tool#comment2403521_546492  With Bitvise SSH Client I can save my password and just push "Login" and it goes directly to the remote desktop.

Comment: is this something between classic X11 and wayland (i heard wayland may not work yet, so disable that). I'd be curious to know.
I have the black screen issue with a mac, but not windows or linux.

Comment: @PeterTeuben I don't know, I was using Windows X2Go client to access it, on Windows 10.